# Configure Multiple Static IPs through NAT on OpenWRT with Nginx

Tags: nat, nginx, switch, openwrt, vlan

Aplogies if this has been asked before, I did a thourough search and didn't find anything quite like it, so I'm hoping someone can either point me in the right direction or lend a hand with the configuration. Here's what I'm working with:

I have 5 static IPs from ISP, coming in to my own router running OpenWRT(its an R6300v2), and I need the router to not only run Nginx, but NAT those 5 IPs via a single trunk line to a Cisco 2690G L2/L3 switch, which then branches out to about two dozen VMs running on four physical hosts.

Now, before getting too crazy technical, I guess my first question is thus: am I better off using a VM to run as firewall/router/nginx server instead of the router? I do have another physical host sitting in standyby if thats the way I should go.

Otherwise, my second question is: how do I combine the nginx and NAT routing so that the traffic comes in on a single WAN port, and out to the switch on a single LAN port? I have a grasp of the basics, and can get things running individually, VLANs, NAT, trunking(somewhat), but the Nginx and combining everything into one config is throwing me for loops.

Again, my apologies if this has been asked/done before, I may not have worded my search properly, and sincerest apologies if this is an entirely greenie question. However, any and all help that can or may be provided would be greatly appreciated.

If it helps, I am the sole tech working this network, I've been building it literally from the ground up, so I have unrestricted access to the machines, the physical plant, all the addressing information, literally everything, so if there are any changes that should be made, or any more info I should provide, please, let me know, I'm happy to oblige.

Thank you very, very much,

Tay